# Codeigniter controllers var

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got a conroller like:

```
class listItems extends CI_Controller{
    private $num;

    public class __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->num=10;
    }

    public class index(){
        echo $this->num;
    }
}
```

when i do this i got nothing. why?

Comment: A class does nothing *unless you call it* somewhere else.  Are you calling it? If so, please show that code so we can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two different classes. Needs to be under the same, so use `function` instead.

```
class listItems extends CI_Controller {

    private $num;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->num=10;
    }

    public function index() {
        echo $this->num;
    }

}
```

Comment: they're fuction (__construct, index)